# Sound preference pane will not open in El Capitan

Tags: audio, logic

My 2.7gHz core i7 mac mini running 10.11.6 will not open the Sound Preferences pane. Since upgrading to Yosemite I have had sound preferences problems.  I produce audio using Logic X and an Apogee ONE audio interface.

Comment: What does "will not open" mean? Does it just keep loading, does it crash something? What have you tried already to resolve the issue?

Comment: @patrix My guess is it says the error "Could not load Sound preference pane", similar to [this post](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/166934/could-not-load-date-time-preference-pane).

Comment: What happens if you boot your Mac Mini into Safe Mode? Can you open the Sound Preferences then? (To boot into Safe Mode, hold the Shift key down while you boot up. To exit Safe Mode, just restart your Mac Mini.)

Answer (score 4):

The only thing that works on my Mac with this problem is running in the console the following command:

```
sudo killall coreaudiod
```